# Right inverse of $f(x)= x^2$ that is not $\pm \sqrt x$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse

I am looking for three different right inverses of $f(x)=x^2$. So far I've only been able to come up with the positive and the negative square roots, $\pm \sqrt x$. Furthermore, the right inverse maps from the positive real numbers to the real numbers.

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: It's the positive real numbers.

Comment: Do you understand my answer below or you need more clarifications?

Comment: There's no need, your answer was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If the domain is positive real numbers, then $f$ is invertible so the right inverse is unique. In particular, $x\mapsto -\sqrt x$ is _not_ a right inverse of $f$.

Comment: yes, the domain should be the whole real numbers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The complete set of right inverse maps is given as follows:

For any $A\subseteq R^+$, be
$$g_A(x) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x} & x\in A\\
-\sqrt{x} & x\notin A
\end{cases}$$

Then $g_A(x)$ is a right inverse to $f(x)=x^2$, and further we have $g_A=g_B \iff A=B$. There are no further right inverses

Proof:

- $g_A$ is a right inverse:

  $$f\circ g_A(x) = \begin{cases}
  \left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = x & x\in A\\
  \left(-\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = x & x\notin A
  \end{cases}$$
- $g_A = g_B \iff A=B$:

  Obviously $A=B\implies g_A=g_B$. Therefore assume $A\ne B$. Therefore there exists a $x$ that is in only one of the sets. Assume w.l.o.g $x\in A$, $x\notin B$. Then $g_A(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g_B(x)=-\sqrt{x}$. Since $x\ne 0$ (because $0\notin\mathbb R^+$), $\sqrt{x}\ne-\sqrt{x}$ and thus $g_A\ne g_B$ since they differ in $x$.
- There are no further right inverses.

  Be $h$ a right inverse of $f$. Then for any $x\in\mathbb R^+_0$ we have $x=f\circ h(x)=(h(x))^2$. But given $x$, the only solutions for $a$ of the equation $x=a^2$ are $a=\sqrt{x}$ and $a=-\sqrt{x}$. Therefore for any $x$, we have either $h(x)=\sqrt{x}$ or $h(x)=-\sqrt{x}$. Be $A=\{x\in\mathbb R^+|h(x)=\sqrt{x}\}$. Then $h(x)=g_A(x)$. $\square$

So you've got $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ different functions to choose from. Choosing an arbitrary set of three of them is left as exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 11):

You might get a combination of the two: $\sqrt x$ when $x<1$, and $-\sqrt x$ when $x\ge 1$, or any other combination (rationals vs irrationals, etc).

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This correctly answers the question. Even more so when DCarter's answer is upvoted and is equivalent to this one.

Comment: Apologies, I'm still sort of new to this site. If I did downvote it, it wasn't intentional.

Comment: @Laura, you can easily check if you did. It will show down arrow red for you. You can click it again to cancel the vote. I'd even advise to upvote it instead (click the up arrow).

Comment: @Laura Pro-tip, undo the downvote before you click the upvote.  >:( Quite an annoying process I do say.

Answer (score 10):

You have identified the *continuous* right inverses.  But think also about discontinuous right inverses such as this, which is defined separately for $x$ rational and irrational:

For $x$ nonnegative rational, $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$

For $x$ positive irrational, $g(x) = -\sqrt{x}$

Comment: what is this answer brings anything new other than rewriting what I said before?

Comment: Your answer is just as good, maybe better.  When several of us are trying to  answer, not aware of the others, how do we get that visibility before we post?   I've just given you an up vote.

Comment: Sorry. I just gave to the community a few nice ideas today, and nobody was nice enough for a thanks or upvote. Having my answer downvoted and exactly the same answer 10 minutes later upvoted was just the last straw.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$, we have that $f$ is surjective. We also know that if $g\colon\Bbb R_{\geq 0}\to \Bbb R$ is its right inverse, then $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}$ and thus $g(x)\in f^{-1}(\{x\}),\ \forall x\in\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$. Conversely, if $g(x)\in f^{-1}(\{x\}),\ \forall x\in\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$, then $g$ is right inverse of $f$. But, for all $x$ we have that $f^{-1}(\{x\}) = \{\sqrt x,-\sqrt x\}$ so any right inverse $g$ of $f$ is of the form

$$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{r l}
\sqrt x,& x\in A\\
-\sqrt x, &x\in \Bbb R_{\geq 0}\setminus A
\end{array}\right.$$

for arbitrary $A\subseteq \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$.